# Creating a POS System in python using Tkinter now I have this error

Tags: python, tkinter, new-operator

I'm just creating my receipt function and my calculation function for my POS system every time I press the "Americano" Button which should add it to the treeviewer list *Which it does* but it doesn't add the prices at the bottom of my UI

This is my function

```
        def Coffee1():
            ItemCost = 3.70
            GST = 2.5
            self.POS_records.insert("", tk.END, values= ("Americano", "1", "3.70"))
            for child in self.POS_records.get_children():
                    ItemCost += float(self.POS_records.item(child, "values")[2])
                    SubTotal_Input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost - 3.7)))
                    GST_Input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost - 2) * GST/100))
                    Total_Input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost -3.7) + (ItemCost - 3) * GST/100))
```

and this is the error I get when I press my Americano button

```
    File "c:\Users\callu\Documents\Major Project\Major test-1.py", line 129, in Coffee1
    GST_Input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost - 2) * GST/100))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float
PS C:\Users\callu\Documents\Major Project>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Would it be more clear if you did ```str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost - 2) * GST/100)))```?  as the string format would apply to the value ```((ItemCost - 2) * GST/100)```.

Comment: What the point of setting same set of variables in a for loop because the final values of the set of variables will be the result of the last iteration? You can update the set of variables after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
def Coffee1():
        ItemCost = 3.70
        GST = 2.5
        self.POS_records.insert("", tk.END, values= ("Americano", "1", "3.70"))
        for child in self.POS_records.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.POS_records.item(child, "values")[2])
                SubTotal_Input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost - 3.7)))
                GST_Input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost - 2) * GST/100)))
                Total_Input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost -3.7) + (ItemCost - 3) * GST/100)))
```

I think, there were grammar issues.
You can see difference between these two.

```
GST_Input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost - 2) * GST/100))
GST_Input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost - 2) * GST/100)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).